# Error in creating static Test suites using Azure Devops REST API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to create a static Test Suite using REST API but i am getting an error in my response.

i am trying to follow the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/test%20%20suites/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops-rest-6.0

My Request Body

```
$body= @"
[ {
  "suiteType": "StaticTestSuite",
  "name": "NewTestSuite",
  "area": {
    "name": "<TeamName>"
  },
  "iteration": "<Iteration>"   
}
]"@

$BuildReqBodyJson = $body | ConvertTo-Json

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Uri  -Method POST -Headers $header -ContentType "application/json"  -Body $BuildReqBodyJson
```

Error :

```
Invoke-RestMethod : {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: 
testSuite","typeName":"System.ArgumentNullException, mscorlib","typeKey":"ArgumentNullException","errorCode":0,"eventId":0}
At

+ $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Uri  -Method POST -Headers $heade ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

Comment: You're passing an array. According to the documentation, it shouldn't be an array.

Comment: I tried removing [] tags in the body , still the same error . 

{"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: 
testSuite","typeName":"System.ArgumentNullException, mscorlib","typeKey":"ArgumentNullException","errorCode":0,"eventId":0}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your request body is incorrect. According to the document there is no `area` or `iteration` properties in the request body.

[image]

See below example request body to create a static Test Suite.

```
$body='
{
  "suiteType": "StaticTestSuite",
  "name": "NewTestSuite"
}
'
```

If you want to create a Test Suite based on a query, you can specify the `queryString` property. See below example.

```
$body='
{
  "suiteType": "DynamicTestSuite",
  "name": "allTestSuite",
  "queryString": "SELECT [System.Id],[System.WorkItemType] FROM WorkItems WHERE [System.WorkItemType] IN GROUP ''Microsoft.TestCaseCategory''  AND [System.AreaPath]=''myareapath'' AND [System.IterationPath] = ''myiterationpath''"
}
```

See the [examples in the document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/test%20%20suites/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#examples) for more information.

Comment: The body tag was the issue. Thanks